# Extracting Pixels From SDL2 Surface Created With SDL_TTF

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm working on a program that creates an SDL_Surface using http://www.fontspace.com/work-ins-studio/variane-script.  I set the background of the surface to be transparent.  Then I extract the pixels from the surface, and place them in part of an opengl texture.

It all works fine, except that the text ends up looking like this (the text should read "testing")

[image: text]

My question: Did I mess up the math somehow and do this myself, or is this just the behaviour of SDL_TTF?  And, if it is just the behaviour of SDL_TTF, how do I work around it to get pixel data that I can use?

Here is the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
//other sdl and opengl overhead stuff here...
TTF_Init();
//shader setup here...
TTF_Font *font;
font = TTF_OpenFont("VarianeScript.ttf", 50);
SDL_Surface* surface;
SDL_Color color = { 255, 0, 0 };
surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, "testing", color);
SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod(surface, 255);
int surfaceWidth = surface->w;
int surfaceHeight = surface->h;
Uint8 red, green, blue, alpha;
float* textImage = new float[(surfaceWidth * surfaceHeight) * 4];
int countText = 0;
SDL_LockSurface(surface);
Uint8* p = (Uint8*)surface->pixels;
for (int y = 0; y < surfaceHeight; ++y) {
    for (int x = 0; x < (surfaceWidth); ++x) {
        Uint8 pixel = p[(y * surface->w) + x];
        SDL_GetRGBA(pixel, surface->format, &red, &green, &blue, &alpha);
        textImage[countText] = ((float)red / 255.0f);
        ++countText;
        textImage[countText] = ((float)green / 255.0f);
        ++countText;
        textImage[countText] = ((float)blue / 255.0f);
        ++countText;
        textImage[countText] = ((float)alpha / 255.0f);
        ++countText;
    }
}
SDL_UnlockSurface(surface);
SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
GLuint texture;
float* image;
int width = 1000, height = 1000;
int textX = width - (int)(width / 1.5);
int textY = height - (int)(height / 1.5);
setupTexture(texture, shader, width, height, image, textImage, textX, textY, surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
//etc...
```

also (the important part starts around where I declare the startpos variables)

```
void setupTexture(GLuint &texture, Shader &shader, int &width, int &height, float* &image, float* text, int textX, int textY, int textW, int textH) {
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
image = new float[(width * height) * 3];
for (int a = 0; a < (width * height) * 3; ) {
    if (a < ((width * height) * 3) / 2) {
        image[a] = 0.5f;
        ++a;
        image[a] = 1.0f;
        ++a;
        image[a] = 0.3f;
        ++a;
    }
    else {
        image[a] = 0.0f;
        ++a;
        image[a] = 0.5f;
        ++a;
        image[a] = 0.7f;
        ++a;
    }
}
int startpos1, startpos2;
for(int y = 0; y < textH; ++y) {
    for(int x = 0; x < textW; ++x) {
        startpos1 = (((y + textY) * width) * 3) + ((x + textX) * 3);
        startpos2 = ((y * textW) *4) + (x * 4);
        if (text[startpos2 + 3] != 0.0) {
            image[startpos1] = text[startpos2];
            image[startpos1 + 1] = text[startpos2 + 1];
            image[startpos1 + 2] = text[startpos2 + 2];
        }
    }
}
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, image);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shader.shaderProgram, "texSampler"), 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
```

Comment: Since your create a tightly packed RGB texture, you have to set [`glPixelStore(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml)

Comment: How would I go about implementing that into my code?  I'm very new to opengl, sorry

Comment: `textX` and `textY` calculated from hardcoded constant 1000 and does not represent actual pitch of `textImage`. What's that constants supposed to mean? Shouldn't it be `surfaceWidth` and `surfaceHeight` instead?

Comment: textX and textY represent the origin (top left corner) of the area where the pixels from text will overwrite those in image

Comment: the problem as I see it isn't with my code per se.  It's that sdl_ttf wraps text around to the front of the pixel array to conserve space (I assume) and I've no idea how to work with that.  Or I could have screwed up the math.  I'll try implementing your code and report back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you extract pixel from surface:

```
Uint8 pixel = p[(y * surface->w) + x];
```

You assume that each pixel takes one byte (could be verified by inspecting `surface->format->BytesPerPixel`), and that each row is `surface->w*1` bytes long - but it isn't. Instead, each row is `surface->pitch` bytes long, so your code should be

```
Uint8 pixel = p[y * surface->pitch + x];
```

(that still assumes it is 1 byte long, but that's beside the point).

It is quite weird that you use floats to represent pixel data, as it gives you nothing here aside from much slower loading.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere that opengl converts 8bit 0-255 values to floats anyway?  Maybe I was mistaken.  Would you recommend just using 8 bit unsigned integers?

Comment: Also I changed the line you suggested, and now the program crashes without displaying anything.  Are any further changes needed to make it work?  Also, I'll check the bytesperpixel, thank you, I was hoping someone would explain to me how to find what I wanted in the format, good.

Comment: I added the line of code: std::cout << (int)surface->format->BytesPerPixel << std::endl;

and it outputs a 1

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to diagnose a crash without any technical information. Run it in debugger to see where and why it crashes. If you can't figure it out, edit that information and current code into the question.

Comment: I also tried BitsPerPixel and it outputs an 8.  I'm not sure why using pitch crashes the program, then, if pitch is the number of bytes per line.

Comment: oh, wait, pitch works now.  Maybe it needed to be rebuilt.  It ALL works now.